# Passing deference variable to a function

Tags: c++, pointers

This may be a trivial question for most but I am new to c++. My question is, how would I pass a pointer which is deference to a function to operate on the pointed value?

```
char first_name[] = "hello";
int myFunc(const char *source){
    innerFunc(char *source){/*append world*/}
}
```

This doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Your use of deference does not make sense here. How are you calling `myFunc`, what is `innerFunc` and `first_name` meant to be doing? Dereferencing a `char*` string, will give you a `char` to the first letter, which does not seem like what you are asking.

Comment: you can't append anything to `first_name`, its an array which is just big enough to hold `"hello"` and its null terminator, use `std::string` instead. If that isn't what you are trying to do post a [mcve]

Comment: Is your question about C or C++ ?

Comment: You can't modify the string literal. If you are forced to use c-strings you will have to  allocate the memory for the string or use the c-string functions. I expect eventually they will teach you how to do this using the standard library instead of what you would do in `c` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example:

```
char first_name[] = "hello";

int inner_func(const char* source) { /* do something, read-only */ }

int my_func(const char* source) {
    inner_func(source);
}
```

So, you merely need to pass the name, that's all.

However, note that you have passed the pointer as `const`, which means that you cannot change it. Appending `world` does not work in that instance. In fact, if you would like to operate on your char string in a changing manner, you would need to create a second `char*` dynamically with the extended size. You cannot change `source`.

Also, inner functions like that cannot be defined in C++. Just define it outside of `myFunc`. You *can* create inner functions with lambdas, but this would be another answer.

Luckily, in C++, manipulating strings is far easier and deeply to recommend:

```
#include <string>

std::string first_name = "hello";

int inner_func(std::string& source) {
    source += " world";
}

int my_func(std::string& source) {
    inner_func(source);
}
```

Now, when you pass a string like first_name to `my_func`, it will be passed to `inner_func` where some string is appended.

Note, though, that `hello world` is quite a strange name, especially as a first name. It might not be what you want.